# Appropriate python web framework for my custom interface

Tags: python, web, frameworks

I'm a newbie in python dev... so be gentle :)

I wrote a script in python with the following syntax structure:

```
def #....

def #...

def #...

def Main():
   #Enter username
   #Enter password
   #Save file to specified location

if __name__ == '__main__':
   Main()
```

I want to build a **minimalist** and **straightforward** python web framework that does the following:

1. Has two url routes:

   a. Homepage to ask for the password and username, supplied to the main body of the python script

   b. Next page to ask for file location to save results.

I need assistance on:

Suggestions on frameworks that can achieve my objective:

Please support your answer with a practical example on how the framework will call the python script I've written above after the I've supplied the **correct** username, password and results location.

I've looked at a couple of web frameworks like:

Django: Steep learning curve

Flask: Not minimal enough for my needs

Comment: Aside note: I have a hard understanding how you won't consider Flask but do consider Django. I see Django as "less minimal" than Flask.
Anyways, have a look [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WebFrameworks).

Answer (score 0):

Let me introduce [Masonite](https://github.com/MasoniteFramework/masonite), The Modern, And Developer Centric Python Web Framework.

1. Ask for password and username:

`def store(self, Request):
    if Auth(Request).login(Request.input('username'), Request.input('password')):
        return Request.redirect_to('ask')`

2. Next page to ask for the file location and save results:

`def upload(self, Upload):
    Upload.driver('disk').store(Request.input('file_upload'))`

Masonite is perfect for this task. Feel free to join [Masonite Slack](http://slack.masoniteproject.com/) channel.

Hope I help.

Comment: Will these functions lie in same scripts as the bottle framework? I cannot also see where you are calling the main program body in your script. Could you give a reproducible example as I asked for?